# Exponent of an operator - Existence/Uniqueness?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following questions: When I can define an Expression $A^p$ with an Operator $A$ and a fractional Exponent $p$?

Is the root (or fractional or even real exponent) existing for arbitrary Operators $A$? 
Is it possible to obtain a unique $B$ with $B:=A^p$?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is definitely yes if the function $x \mapsto x^p$ is a bounded and measurable function on the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of the operator $A$ and the operator $A$ is bounded and self-adjoint. (It might also be true if $A$ is unbounded, but I haven't yet studied unbounded operators, so I can't say anything about that case). This is because of the [spectral theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Bounded_self-adjoint_operators) that gives you

$$ A = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda\; dE$$

Where $E$ is a spectral measure. The operator you are looking for can then be written as

$$ A^p = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda^p \;dE $$

Answer (score 0):

**Preliminary Remark**

There's no need of bounded operators nor bounded functions!

**Banach Spaces**

Here the natural operators are the closed ones.

One then has the holomorphic functional calculus.

**Example**

*(Does someone have an interesting example therefor?)*

**Hilbert Spaces**

Here the natural operators are the normal ones.

One then has the measurable functional calculus.

**Example**

Consider a Hamiltonian:
$$H:\mathcal{D}(H)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad H=H^*$$

Then one can regard its density:
$$\rho:=\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta H}}:\mathcal{D}(\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta H}})\to\mathcal{H}$$
*(One has to be careful about its domain, however.)*